# .htaccess login and redirect based on username and password

Tags: .htaccess, login-script

Been searching around for a .htaccess code but I just couldn't find the right one. I have a website which is password protected by .htaccess. What I need now is to redirect users (after they login) based on their username and password. ie.

user1 with password:xxx would be redirected to mysite.com/page1, user2 with password:xxx would be redirected to mysite.com/page2 and user3 with password:xxx would be redirected to mysite.com/page3

Can this be done with .htaccess and if so, what the code would be?``

Thank you!

Comment: The proper way of doing this is using server-side script (PHP,ASP.NET etc) and not .htaccess -- **especially** from security point of view.

Comment: I know I can do this with PHP or ASP but I need to do this with .htaccess...if there is a way.

Comment: You can check user name (only after user will be authenticated by Apache HTTP Authorisation) by checking `%{REMOTE_USER}` but you will not see the password (unless you parse "Authorisation" header, but password will be "encrypted" anyway). So yeah -- something like that is possible (at least I'm expecting this to work).