# How to reverse proxy an Nginx server to different web apps based on username and password

Tags: nginx, server, reverse-proxy, basic-authentication, nginx-reverse-proxy

### Context:

I have two identical python web apps running on ports `http://localhost:6001/` and `http://localhost:6002/`respectively. Both of these apps serve the same end points but they process input data (from users) slightly differently. We can consider them as dev instance and staging instance.

Now I want to add Nginx web server as a reverse proxy for both of these websites. There are 2 reasons for this:

1. I don't want users to access these two ports directly. I want to hide these 2 ports from public and make them accessible via only the port on which Nginx server is listening. Let's say it is listening on port `7000`
2. To add a username password setup to authenticate the users (with the help of auth_basic and proxy_pass provided by Nginx)

### Current Setup:

First I tried implementing the basic auth for one app. I have a file named `pyapp` under `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. I linked the same file to the location `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. The configuration file looks like this:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server{
    listen 7000;
    server_name _;
    
    location / {
            auth_basic "baisc auth";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

    location ^~ /static {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/static/;
    }

    location ^~ /healthz {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/healthz/;
    }

    location ^~ /vendor {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/vendor/;
    }
    
    location /stream { # this is a socket

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/stream/;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

With this setup, when I directly enter `http://127.0.0.1:7000/` in my browser, I get the prompt to enter username and password. I enter the credentials which are present in `.htpasswd` file (which I created). Now I get to see the app which is running on port `6001` while the address in browser still shows `http://127.0.0.1:7000/`. So far so good.

### Question:

Is there a way that I can do a conditional proxy_pass based on the username and password entered? basically when user visits `http://127.0.0.1:7000/`

- if username1 and password1 are entered, then load the app from port `6001`
- if username2 and password2 are entered, then load the app from port `6002`

I'm aware that we can get the details of authenticated user with `$REMOTE_USER` and also use a variable (something like `$app_port`) for storing the port of the app (idea is to replace harcoded `6001` with this variable and set it to 6001 or 6002 based on `$REMOTE_USER`). But I'm new to Nginx and not aware if this is actually possible because I couldn't find much info regarding this

It will be of great help if anyone can point me to the right documentation. Thanks a ton!!

PS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293076/htaccess-login-and-redirect-based-on-username-and-password) is a similar question that is close to what I want to do. Please let me know if I can provide more relevant information which improves clarity.